Bitcoin Meta tags descriptions
Is there a way to write tag descriptions in the meta part of this SE? I tried doing that just now and I don't seem to be able to (whereas on the main SE there is no problem with that).

Unfortunately, tag-wiki creation / editing is not supported on the meta sites at present.

Can you make that into an answer? When I tried copying yours, the SE claimed it was a trivial answer and moved it as a comment.

Heh... Oops - that happened to me as well. ;-P

Unfortunately, tag-wiki creation / editing is not supported on the meta sites at present:

We're not currently allowing tag wikis to be edited on metas, as we plan to push out the shared meta tag wikis from meta.so.
This may change in the future.

